# Should the deploy script be an artifact of the build?

Tags: deployment, jenkins, builds

This is a web project written in Java.

So, I'm writing the build and the deploy scripts. To create the build, I used ant. The continuous build is done with Jenkins.

The build generates 3 different artifacts:

1. The war file
2. A zip with layouts
3. A zip with images

So far, so good, but now I need to write the deploy script, which should:

- Deploy the war (artifact 1) to the tomcat running at *server 1*
- Place the artifact **2** at *server 1* in a specific directory
- Place the artifact **3** at *server 2* in a specific directory

So I was talking with my colleague and he said that we should also generate an artifact (maybe *deploy.xml*) that deploys these artifacts when placed at the correct server.

So there would be another script, that would:

- Download the jenkins artifacts
- scp to each server and place the deploy.xml there
- remotely invoke the deploy.xml

What makes me a little uncomfortable is the act of having the deploy.xml as a build artifact. The motivation behind this would be to be able to make a deploy without needing to have access to the VCS repositories, so a build would be self-contained, ie, any build could go into production only with what was generated by Jenkins.

Where should the deploy scripts be placed? Should they be **only** at the VCS or should they be build artifacts too?

Comment: this question is good / it makes us want to plus-one / wish i could answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My experience is that everything that *can* be automated should be. If you can describe it as *step 1, step 2, ....* then it should be a script. If the script can be auto-generated to include build specific info (e.g. revision tag), then that's what you should do. This is not for the sake of being lazy, but for the sake of being *predictable* and *reproducible*.

Note bene: you should also have an auto-generated *revert script* that can be used by anyone on the team in case the auto-generated deploy script goes bat sh*t crazy and hoses the production server.

Answer (score 3):

All that Peter Rowell wrote, is correct, in addition I would:

For the deploy script file

- if it was written by someone, it needs to be in version control.
- if it was generated and can be generated again, it usually does not go into version control.

For the deploy process:

- If you like your artefacts to be self-contained and if it could be done easily, then the file could be a build artefact, meaning that it's packaged with the build result in such a manner that it's usable for deployment.
- On the other hand, deployments get more and more complex so sooner or later you will need a dedicated program (read some code) that does the deployment and a Jenkins build artefact is not self contained any more.

This is rather depending on your process and how you like to handle deployments.